# How to use chromedriver and selenium through python in alpine

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, alpine-linux

In alpine I run the following two commands:

```
apk update
apk add chromium chromium-chromedriver
```

I would now like to use the chromedriver with selenium via python. In windows I would do something like the following while having the .exe in the same directory.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
```

How do I use the chromedriver I just installed using apk add in alpine.

PS: the selenium library was installed via pip install.

Comment: Check this [link it May Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155839/selenium-with-python-chromedriver-have-to-be-in-path)